# What would you call this cut out space in a panel?

Tags: single-word-requests

What would you call this in English? A Notch / Cavity or something else?

The half panel length needs to be corrected with the width of the "Notch"

[image: Notch Cavity]

Comment: Perhaps a [**slot**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/slot). English speakers would know what was meant.

Comment: Notch or slot..

Answer (score 1):

***Notch*** would be a reasonable everyday term, though it has many synonyms - *cleft, cut, groove, indent* etc.

However I believe the technical term in woodworking or masonry is a ***rebate*** (N. American ***rabbet***)

The OED provides this as sense 1a of *rebate* as used in carpentry or masonry (clearly *rebate* has other meanings - including the obvious commercial one).

> A recess or step cut along or into the edge of a piece of wood, stone,
>   or other material and usually intended to form a joint with another
>   piece or to receive a door, windowpane, etc.; = rabbet n. 1. In North
>   America the more usual form is rabbet (see rabbet n. I.).
>
> 2004   Sunday Mail (S. Afr.) (Nexis) 19 Dec. h10   How to replace a
>   small broken window... Remove old putty with a chisel and take out
>   broken glass. Clean out rebate with a chisel to remove any remaining
>   putty.

Under ***rabbet*** the following is given:

> (a) A channel, groove, or slot, cut along the edge or face of a piece
>   of wood or other material and intended to receive the edge or end of
>   another piece or a tongue made specially to fit (now rare);  (b) a
>   rectangular recess made along a projecting angle or arris to form a
>   step or shoulder. Cf. rebate n.2 Both forms are extensively used in
>   joining or framing wood, the two pieces being commonly either in the
>   same plane or at right angles to each other. In a double rabbet (in
>   sense 1a(b)) the shoulder on one piece fits into the rabbet of the
>   other. In Masonry, a rabbet (in sense 1a(b)) is often made to receive
>   the edge of a door, window, etc.; in picture frames the rabbet
>   receives the edges of the glass. (b).  †(a) A tongue to fit into a
>   groove (obsolete);  (b) any one of the sides of a rabbet made in an
>   arris; a shoulder, a ledge.

Comment: A rebate (rabbit or rabbet in UK too) is usually a *longitudinal* groove. A notched cut-out is a *mortise* or *mortice* (UK).

Comment: @WeatherVane also a rebate does not usually penetrate through the material. For example the part of a door frame into which the door fits is a rebate. The slot in the photo is one part of a _half-lapped_ joint.